# How to update the value instantly after getting the push notification in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have used Push notification in my application, when the notification arrives i will get some values in the payload and i need to update the values in my application. I have amount label in all the views, so i need to update the amount after receiving the notification. But the problem is, the value doesn't update instantly, when i navigate to any view after that it will update. I want to update the value instantly, so how can i do that?

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

            NSString *getAmt =[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"Amount"];
            float totalAmt = [getAmt floatValue] + [amt floatValue];
            NSString *finalAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",totalAmt];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:finalAmount forKey:@"amount"];
            [self.viewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I am using the Nsuserdefault value for displaying the amount in the amount label. Now the values are changed, when i am navigates to any view after that it will update. But i want to update the value instantly in my application, after getting the notification. So please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSNotication and add a notification against a method of class where method is implemented, when you receive push notification, post that notification and in method update values

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for this purpose..

Register you desired `UIViewController` in `NSNotificationCenter` for `@"NotificaitonRecivied"`
like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector: @selector(updateAmount:)
                                                     name: @"NotificaitonRecivied" 
                                                   object: nil];
```

now whenever you receive any updated amount, simply broadcast a notification like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificaitonRecivied" object:nil];
```

`updateAmount:` amount will be a method to read your amount from `NSUserDefaults` to set it on any `View`